# Download HTML table to Excel by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, flask, compiler-errors, download

In my Flask application, I created a button to extract the content of an HTML table into an Excel file. I used Javascript to extract from my interface the content of my HTML table in Excel format.

Unfortunately, when I run the code below, the downloaded Excel file is empty. Could you please help to correct my code below. Thanks.

```
function exportTableToExcel(filename = ''){
let downloadLink;
let dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
let tableSelect = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
let tableHTML = tableSelect[0].outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

// Specify file name
filename = 'All_Issues.xls';

// Create download link element
downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
        type: dataType
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
}else{
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    
    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getElementsByTagName() function returns an array so you have to get the first element.

```
let tableHTML = tableSelect[0].outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, there are no more error messages but my code above still doesn't work perfectly because  unfortunately the Excel file download is empty. Can you provide me guideline to correct my script above ?